# Setting php sessions

Tags: php, session

I can't figure out why these sessions are not being set. My code seems to be the same as all the tutorials - and stack overflow questions - but it just won't set a session. Please tell me if I'm going wrong somewhere.

Here's the basics: I have a hmtl page with a form that adds an email address and a password to a database. After the insert to the db, I'm trying to start a session, then redirect the user to a new page and check if the session is set. If there's no session the user gets redirected away from the protected page.

This is the code that runs the database insert and is supposed to set the session, but doesn't:

```
<?php
// connect to db manager
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if (!$link) {die('Database Error: Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());}

// select db
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('foo', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}

// username and password sent from form
$em = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$pw = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

// MySQL Insert Statement
$insert = "INSERT INTO users (`email`, `password`) VALUES ('$em',AES_ENCRYPT('$pw','SecretKey'))";

// Perform Query
$execute = mysql_query($insert);

// if inserted, start session + variable, then redirect
if ($execute) {
 session_start();
 $_SESSION["signUp"];
 echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
 echo 'document.location.href = "../u/user.php";';
 echo '</script>';
}
else{
  $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
  $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
  die($message);
}

mysql_close($link);
?>
```

And this is the code at the top of the protected page:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION['signUp'])){
  echo "Session not set!";
  // header("location:../index.php");
}
?>
```

I have the redirect commented out so that I can test if the session is being set. Every time I run the form I get redirected to the ../u/user.php"; page and I get the error message saying that the session is not set.

Comment: you cannot start session at middle of your code. you have to define it at top of your page.

Comment: It's not necessary. Session must be started before you send something to client, but it doesn't required to start it at beginning of file.

Comment: I just changed the code and the start of the session is still in the middle and the code works, so I don't think it needs to be at the top of the page either.

Comment: try to replace `empty($_SESSION['signUp'])` with `isset($_SESSION['signUp'])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi you have not assigned any value to your `session`

```
if ($execute) {
 session_start();
 $_SESSION["signUp"];// where is the value for this ????
// $_SESSION["signUp"] = true; or whatever you want

 echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
 echo 'document.location.href = "../u/user.php";';
 echo '</script>';
}
```

**Also start seesion at top of your page**

Comment: Thanks. That's probably in the tutorials somewhere but I must have missed it.

Answer (score 2):

you need to set a value to `$_SESSION['signUp']` maybe something like `$_SESSION['signUp'] = true;`

Comment: Second part is correct but the first part (top of page) is not correct

Answer (score 0):

you can replace `empty` to `isset`